# product attributes for magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

This is my first time posting so I hope I give enough detail. I am trying to retrieve all the product attributes with their respective labels. 
Using: V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=attribute_code&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={attrCode}&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

I can retrieve the specific ids for a specific attribute code, if I try:

V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_type_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={entity_type_id}&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

**I get the following error:**
Generated output:
iwwshr.Exceptions.WebServiceCallFailedException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. ProtocolError http://VMDP-200CRM2011:8081/magento/rest/default/V1/products/attributes?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_type_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
the web server returned:
{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-57cd41117122e"}
   at Tool.Classes.Runtime.HttpOperationWrapper.DoCall()
   at Tool.Classes.Runtime.HttpOperationWrapper.DoSampleCall(String xmlCallData)

**Going to the logs I get:**
Report ID: webapi-57cd41117122e; Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_type_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.attribute_id) FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS `entity_type` ON main_table.entity_type_id = entity_type.entity_type_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` ON main_table.attribute_id = eav_entity_attribute.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON main_table.attribute_id = additional_table.attribute_id WHERE (`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product') AND (`entity_type_id` = '4')' in C:\wamp64\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor.php:194

**The query being run is:**
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.attribute_id) FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS `entity_type` ON main_table.entity_type_id = entity_type.entity_type_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` ON main_table.attribute_id = eav_entity_attribute.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON main_table.attribute_id = additional_table.attribute_id WHERE (`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product') AND (`entity_type_id` = '4')

**Which returns:**
Error Code: 1052. Column 'entity_type_id' in where clause is ambiguous

**If I change the query to:**
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.attribute_id) FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS `entity_type` ON main_table.entity_type_id = entity_type.entity_type_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` ON main_table.attribute_id = eav_entity_attribute.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON main_table.attribute_id = additional_table.attribute_id WHERE (`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product') AND (**`main_table`**.`entity_type_id` = '4')

**A row is returned.**

Maybe I am doing something wrong but I am not sure how else to retrieve all the product attributes???

Comment: You should read [ask].